# denomination of coins in def main() python

Tags: python

I am writing a script that asks the user for the numbers of coins of different denominations that they have, then displays the total sum in dollars and cents.

I am stuck at this point and am confused on what exactly is wrong. This is part of my intro class, so detail to what needs to be changed is greatly appreciated. The output I need is to tell the user how many dollars and left over cents there are. I am having a problem now with the output. The function tells me the right answer but when wording the answer the cent(s) are off.
For example when pennies are 5; nickels 3; dimes 3; quarters 3, the total is 1.25 but the function says "You have 1 dollars and 1 cent(s)"

```
def main():
    pennies = get_input("Enter pennies  : ")
    nickels = get_input("Enter nickels  : ")
    dimes = get_input("Enter dimes    : ")
    quarters = get_input("Enter quarters : ")

    print("You entered : ")
    print("\tPennies   : " , pennies)
    print("\tNickels   : " , nickels)
    print("\tDimes     : " , dimes)
    print("\tQuarters  : " , quarters)

    total_value = get_total(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
    dollars = get_dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
    left_over_cents = get_left_over_cents(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)

    print("Total = $",format(total_value, ".2f"), sep="")
    print("You have", dollars, "dollars and", left_over_cents, "cent(s)")

def get_input(message):
    get_input = int(input(message))
    while get_input <= 0:
        print("Error")
        get_input = int(input(message))
    return get_input

def get_total(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters):
    pennies = (.01 * pennies);
    nickels = .05 * nickels;
    dimes = .10 * dimes;
    quarters = .25 * quarters;
    total_value = pennies + nickels + dimes + quarters
    return total_value

def get_dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters):
    total_value = get_total(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
    dollars = format(total_value // 1, ".0f")
    return dollars

def get_left_over_cents(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters):
    total_value = get_dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
    left_over_cents = total_value
    return left_over_cents

main()
```

Comment: Please post the errors you are getting.

Comment: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType' is the error that is coming up.

Comment: Please do not edit the question to a different question after it has been answered. Now the correct answer does not reflect the question at all and is useless for anyone who finds this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error actually lives in your `get_input` method.

```
def get_input(message):
  get_input = int(input(message))
  while get_input <= 0:
    print("Error")
    get_input = int(input(message))
    return get_input
```

which returns `None` if the original input is > 0. You might want to unindent the `return` clause once.

Comment: What would be wrong for why my written answer is coming out wrong? I am assuming somewhere in the left_over_cents.